# Error while opening encoder for output stream ffmpeg from php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I try to run this command in `php` with `exec`

`'ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' '/home/api/test.mp4' '-async' '1' '-metadata:s:v:0' 'start_time=0' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/home/api/tmp/unb2a/pass-62aeeac90d83c' '/home/api/Pre_zygJYg1.mp4' 2>&1`

and my output is

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/api/test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp42iso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2022-06-18T07:02:26.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 1.4.2 2021100300
  Duration: 00:00:59.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2694 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 2524 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-06-18T07:02:26.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 161 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-06-18T07:02:26.000000Z
      handler_name    : Stereo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
-async is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0.
[libx264 @ 0x5640d624b2c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x5640d624b2c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x5640d62b9580] Qavg: 6009.205
[aac @ 0x5640d62b9580] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

When I run this command in the terminal it **works**, But its not working when I'm using `exec`

**UPDATED**
This issue happened when I changed my webserver from apache to openlitespeed

Comment: Are you using the same version? The one posted is quite old. Consider updating ffmpeg first

Comment: @kesh its lastest version for ubunto. also yes its same version